# Noob here - pygame animation of my sprite updates when I move the mouse on screen

Tags: python, pygame

noob here, I am experiencing a weird glitch or bug maybe, I have this code

```
elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        frames = 0
        frames_count = 0
```

This code stops the counter from moving except when I move my mouse onto the window it ignores the frame_count = 0 and starts the counting again, the code below I have made a new veriable called timer so it actually changes the number this some what fixes my issue but I am more confused as to why the code above alone doesnt work just fine, is it a glitch/bug or just my bad coding haha, on the bottom is more of a hack job, I would prefer it to just be frames_count = 0 instead of adding a completely new variable called timer.

```
   import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

resWidth = 800
resheight = 600
# Setup the game window + Name and Icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
icon = pygame.image.load("gameicon.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((resWidth, resheight), RESIZABLE)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# PLayer
x = 350
y = 300
width = 40
height = 80
vel = 0.19  # The speed of the character

spritesheet = pygame.image.load("SpriteSheet.png")

frames_left = []
frames_left.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(0, 50, 20, 47)))
frames_left.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(50, 50, 25, 47)))
frames_left.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(100, 50, 22, 47)))
frames_left.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(150, 50, 22, 47)))
frames_left.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(200, 50, 24, 47)))
frames_left.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(250, 50, 28, 47)))
frames_left.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(300, 50, 23, 47)))
frames_left.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(350, 50, 22, 47)))
frames_left.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(400, 50, 21, 47)))

frames_right = []
frames_right.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(0, 150, 20, 47)))
frames_right.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(50, 150, 25, 47)))
frames_right.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(100, 150, 22, 47)))
frames_right.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(150, 150, 22, 47)))
frames_right.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(200, 150, 24, 47)))
frames_right.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(250, 150, 28, 47)))
frames_right.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(300, 150, 23, 47)))
frames_right.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(350, 150, 22, 47)))
frames_right.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(400, 150, 21, 47)))

frames_up = []
frames_up.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(0, 0, 50, 50)))
frames_up.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(50, 0, 50, 50)))
frames_up.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(100, 0, 50, 50)))
frames_up.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(150, 0, 50, 50)))
frames_up.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(200, 0, 50, 50)))
frames_up.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(250, 0, 50, 50)))
frames_up.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(300, 0, 50, 50)))
frames_up.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(350, 0, 50, 50)))
frames_up.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(400, 0, 50, 50)))

frames_down = []
frames_down.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(0, 100, 50, 50)))
frames_down.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(50, 100, 50, 50)))
frames_down.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(100, 100, 50, 50)))
frames_down.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(150, 100, 50, 50)))
frames_down.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(200, 100, 50, 50)))
frames_down.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(250, 100, 50, 50)))
frames_down.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(300, 100, 50, 50)))
frames_down.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(350, 100, 50, 50)))
frames_down.append(spritesheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(400, 100, 50, 50)))

animations = {
    'left': frames_left,
    'right': frames_right,
    'up': frames_up,
    'down': frames_down
}
player_direction = 'down'
frames = 0
frame_count = 0
timer = 1
# Colours
red = (255, 0, 0)
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

# Game Loop
while True:
    screen.fill(white)  # Makes things visible

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()  # Make the quit button work

        if event.type == VIDEORESIZE:  # Makes the window resize not glitch
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode((event.w, event.h), RESIZABLE)

    frame_count += timer  # timer continues moving
    if frame_count >= 100:  # if "number" frames have passed
        frame_count = 0  # reset the counter
        frames = (frames + 1) % len(animations[player_direction])

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()  # Movement for the player
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -= vel
        player_direction = 'left'
        timer = 1
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += vel
        player_direction = 'right'
        timer = 1
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        y -= vel
        player_direction = 'up'
        timer = 1
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y += vel
        player_direction = 'down'
        timer = 1
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        frames = 0
        timer = 0

    screen.blit(animations[player_direction][frames], (x, y))
    # pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, (x, y, width, height))
    # Draws a rectangle (resolution, colour, location x, location y, shape
    pygame.display.flip()  # Updates everything!
```

Comment: Hi Dragon, welcome to SO! Please familiarise yourself with [writing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking your next one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not processing the `pygame.KEYUP` event properly.

Since it's an *event* case, it needs to be handled in the event processing loop, not in the part that checks for key-presses:

```
if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
    y += vel
    player_direction = 'down'
    timer = 1
elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:      # <-- SHOULD NOT BE HERE
    frames = 0
    timer = 0
```

But in with the other events:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        sys.exit()  # Make the quit button work

    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:   # If *any* key released
        if event.key == pygame.K_r     # 'r' for Reset
            frames = 0
            timer = 0

    elif event.type == VIDEORESIZE:  # Makes the window resize not glitch
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((event.w, event.h), RESIZABLE)
```

Note that your existing code resets the timer on any key release.  This sounds wrong to me since it will fire on any of your movement keys being released - maybe this is what you intended.  The example code above only resets `frames` and `timer` if the key released is `r`.

Comment: thank you for the reply, yes the code is supposed to stop the timer every time a movement key is pressed because of how the animation works it keeps moving if I don't reset the timer, with the code like this when a key is pressed the timer starts and the animation plays, I can see how in the future this could cause a problem I will leave it for now, and thank you for the code placement I will change it straight away! @Kingsley

Comment: okay I have changed your         `if event.key == pygame.K_r ` to just to "if keys" this should make it so when keys gets released it should `frames = 0 timer = 0` as you mentioned a problem with any key pressed on the keyboard would reset the timer, does this look correct to you?

Comment: @Dragon20C - Yes, you could just remove the `event.key == pygame.K_r` clause, then it will happen on every KEY-UP event.